# Python how to sort this list?

Tags: python, list

```
lst = [(1,(1,3,5)), (5,(2,3,4)),(3,(2,3,4))]
```

I want to sort by the first value, descending order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just like this:

```
sorted(lst, reverse=True)
```

Comment: to every other answerer: the index is not required. Python always sorts lists by the first element it finds.

Comment: actually, Python compares tuples by lexicographic order, so it does not only sort lists/tuples by their first elements. This distinction is important if a "stable" sorting by first element is desired.

Answer (score 6):

Sort in place?  Use:

```
lst.sort(reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import operator
sorted(lst, reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(list, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Note also that "list" isn't a great name for your list because it's the built-in list type.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort like this.

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda a: a[0], reverse=True)
```